# For a rutted farm road, what is needed to fix it and how much worse would it get?

Tags: outdoor, driveway, soil

On a vacant lot in the northeast US, used for haying in the past, myself and a few other people started different farming projects on it. It is very wet and had an especially wet year in the past. Traffic is relatively low but we do drive pickup trucks on the field during the growing season and have had very occasional heavier trucks deliver materials.

The path we drive on is now very rutted, as expected. Road work was planned before the past growing season but was not completed. We're still trying to line up some basic road work, expecting that means installing a culvert and a gravel driveway for the worst spots. We're getting pros on it ASAP but they are busy.

My question for this community is what kind of activities would you expect to fix ruts like this, and how much worse do these issues get each year they go unaddressed? I understand compaction gets worse and the soil will only become more and more likely to puddle and become inaccessible more frequently and longer - I'm looking for confirmation and clarifications about that.

Here's some pictures.

This is entering the field. You're on a paved town road, then you pull off onto 20x20ft gravel driveway the town built, and that slopes down into this muddy path.
[image: front field entrance]

This is between two fields on site, over a hundred feet away from the entrance in the image above. This is a clearer case of a culvert being needed along with plenty of gravel.
[image: back field entrance]

Between the two images is about 150ft of rutted ground that stays relatively dry. We are thinking these two problem areas need 50ft or so of proper gravel driveway installed and a culvert in one or both areas. For the drier stretch we're thinking pickup trucks and the soil can tolerate it, and ideally we will at least spread 3-4 inches of woodchips every few years, to make a path that gets less degraded each use.

Comment: The only way to determine price is to get quotes from local companies. That's why shopping/pricing questions are explicitly off topic here. Please edit out that part of your question.

Comment: Wood chips probably will not work well.  They get wet and rot, plus they keep the ground from drying out.  You end up with wet ground with gooey stuff on top.

Comment: @FreeMan I am not looking for an exact price, just a list of likely tasks needed and rough ballpark of what that costs, to help me work with local companies. Does that still need to be edited out?

Comment: @crip659 I have seen them work and for the drier part I think it could. I realize the wetter areas will need better than woodchips. Examples of woodchip driveways: https://homeguides.sfgate.com/create-wood-chip-driveway-32638.html and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-zc113e8L8

Comment: I have used bark mulch as I got it for free at my last job. It takes quite a bit to fill the ruts and mix with the mud. After getting enough to support trucks/tractor packed in I had to add about 1-2 inches every other year to the path where the tires traveled not as good as crushed quarry but it was easier on my horses feet than rock.

Comment: Part of your question is about cost, and that's strictly off topic. The other is speculative and subjective. That's not ideal for DIYSE either. Please revise to ask something more specific.

Comment: The main problem is that you don't _have_ a road. You have organic topsoil, which can't be repaired piecemeal. That's a non-starter. Get an estimate from a local excavator.

Comment: This answer suggests another approach - the "drive on grid" products that spread vehicle load and wear over grassed surfaces. https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/15444/18078

Comment: Even rough estimates of pricing are off-topic because pricing can vary so much by locale.

Comment: How long do you expect your road works to last? In increasing order of longevity, I'd suspect: 1) Nothing, 2) Wood/bark chips, 3) Gravel, 4) Asphalt, 5) Concrete. It also depends on whether you properly prepare a road bed or just dump material on top of the ground.

Comment: for the dry areas, drive next to the ruts.  It will push some of the soil into the low points, and if you continue to drive on the high points it will eventually even out.  It might be a bit bumpy at first if your ruts are really deep.

Comment: LOL. Even out. That's a good one, city dweller. :P

Comment: Yeah I don't know about the even out part from @rtaft, we have already tried driving next to ruts and it just spreads the mess.

Comment: I think my ultimate question here is, what kind of fixes are needed (which there are already answers for) and: **What happens if we do not fix this for another 1, 2, 5 years? What piecemeal fixes can we do to minimize harm?**

Comment: @isherwood ha, never lived in a city except for my college years.  I have a nice long 'gravel' driveway, not quite the same thing but I get several inch deep ruts where the larger vehicle parks especially in the spring and I just avoid the ruts and it eventually evens out until the next spring.

Answer (score 2):

The key to road maintenance is **water**. Specifically getting rid of it, getting it OFF the road as soon as possible (even in deserts.)

You can build the roadbed up with stone or gravel so it's higher, and crown it (shape higher in the middle, lower on the edges) so water runs off of it, not along it. You should relocate the topsoil onto your growing areas and start building from subsoil.

You can ditch beside the road to take water away, but you still have to fill in the ruts and crown the road so water goes into the ditch, not sitting in the ruts. And the ditch has to go somewhere lower to take the water away.

Tile drains (perforated pipes) can help PART of the year, but are ineffective in times when the ground is frozen between the surface and the drain. Ditches are simple and reliable.

While a road grader is "ideal" - if you have farm tractors available you can manage the earthmoving with those. On average tractors are less destructive than trucks, where you have a choice of what to drive onto the field.

As you are in the USA, speak to your agricultural extension agent, who probably has pamphlets or web sites on building and maintaining farm roads. They **might** even come take a look when they are in the area and offer specific advice.

Geotextiles can help to keep the dirt from "eating" your stone or gravel materials (which may otherwise sink into the muck, requiring constant reapplication.)

If you don't fix it it **will** get worse, especially if you keep driving on it when wet. You can already see that you are losing soil in the second picture, and ruts will only erode deeper with time, water and additional driving on them - though time and water will keep  working once started, even if you stop driving on them.

Using free woodchips (copiously) is certainly a lot better than doing nothing while waiting for money for gravel/stone.

Comment: See also: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/43880/18078

Comment: This from the UN FAO https://www.fao.org/3/S1250E/S1250E1b.htm has specific guidance and diagrams for building roads and ditches that reduce erosion.